# My game still showing Navigation bar

Tags: android, android-layout, navigationbar

I was wondering I do my best to hide Navigation bar from my game but event I added code below into my activity the navigation bar still showing as attached picture.

```
View decorView = getWindow().getDecorView();
int uiOptions = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN;
decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(uiOptions);
```

[image]
Anyone have any idea on this issue? or I miss something in code.

Best Regards,

Answer (score 0):

Try using `immersive` mode to hide `System UI` in conjunction with what you have used as in

```
 decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(
            View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION // hide nav bar
            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN // hide status bar
            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE);
```

Comment: Dear Rajan Ks, I already add this code but still the same. Can you give me more details? thank you sir.